# Java Compile time parameter interdependency

Tags: java, generics, enums, compilation

I'm designing an event driven system which sends events with some data to a queue. The listener on the queue dispatches the messages via javax.enterprise.event, I have methods listening to these events via observerving qualifiers.
The system behaves like I'd expect but I'm missing compile-time type validation.
Some basic code can be found below:

```
public interface IEventSender {
    void send(final ServerEventTypeEnum serverEventTypeEnum, final IEventData eventData);
}


public class ObservingClientClass{
    public void eventAProcessService(@Observes @IEventTypeQualifier(EVENT_1) ServerEventMessage serverEventMessage) {
        //handle the event, cast the data to concrete implementation X
        (X) serverEventMessage.getEventData()
    }
}

public enum ServerEventTypeEnum implements IEventTypeEnum {
    EVENT_1,
    EVENT_2
}

public interface IEventData extends Serializable{
}


public class X implements IEventData {
}
public class Y implements IEventData {
}
```

- The ServerEventTypeEnum is just some Enum with the types of events I
  support.
- The eventData is just a generic interface which the actual eventData
  classes implement.
- The ServerEventMessage is just a wrapper class which contains the eventData and some other data which is not relevant to this problem.

The problem is that for EventTypeEnum 1, the observering qualifiers expects a concrete implementation of type X and for EvenTypeEnum 2 they expect eventData of concrete type Y. At this moment the observing clients cast the IEventData to a concrete class.

This means that when I'm sending eventData messages to the queue, I always have to check what the client code expects to receive, with the risk of a classcastException at runtime.
I'm wondering if there's some way, maybe with generics, I can use to define the expected implementation type in my send method.

I want to specify the relation between the eventType and the concrete implementations in the Enum itself. What do I have to change in my 'send' method to get compiletime type validation? Example of what I want to do with my Enum:

```
public enum ServerEventTypeEnum implements IEventTypeEnum {
    EVENT_1(X.class),
    EVENT_2(Y.class);

    private ServerEventTypeEnum(Class concreteImplementationOfTheEventData) {
    //set the fields...
    }
}
```

Technology:

- Java SE 8
- Java EE 7

Comment: CDI, which is built-into JEE7, already has a powerful & type-safe events mechanism. Why don't you check that, instead of creating your own?

Comment: I'm already using CDI its event mechanism. In our system we have over 100 events defined. Some of these events trigger costly processes. I need those events to scale through our cluster and to be transactional. For this reason we first post it on a queue and next fire them with CDI its event mechanism. The problem is that I want type safety, but I also want an easy way to define a new event (by adding it as a enum and linking its payload type). The payloads of these events are mostly the same. That's why I don't want to create a new class, qualifier and payload every time I need a new event.